# Kivy accordion interaction

Tags: python, input, mouse, coordinates, kivy

I have images loading in the kivy accordion and I want to print out the x and y coordinates below the images when I press the mouse button. I can't for the life of my figure this out. Every time I add anything it seems like it shuts the whole program down.  I know that the widget I have will print to the console but I want to print it to the screen.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MouseWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
    root = Accordion(orientation='horizontal')

    item= AccordionItem(title='Picture1')
    src = "picture1.png"
    image = Image(source=src,pos=(200, 100))
    # add image to AccordionItem
    item.add_widget(image)
    root.add_widget(item)


    item= AccordionItem(title='Picture2')
    src = "picture2.png" 
    image = Image(source=src,pos=(200, 100))
    # add image to AccordionItem
    item.add_widget(image)
    root.add_widget(item)

    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple modification to your program that adds the touch position to a label below the image, using kivy language to automatically bind to the necessary properties so that the display is updated when they change.

I'm not sure what problems you had in particular, so let me know if the way it works is not clear!

```
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MouseWidget>:
    image: image
    label: label
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: image
        source: root.source
    Label:
        id: label
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        text: 'no touch detected'

''')

class MouseWidget(BoxLayout):
    image = ObjectProperty()
    label = ObjectProperty()
    source = StringProperty()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.label.text = str(touch.pos)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.label.text = 'no touch detected'


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Accordion(orientation='horizontal')

        item= AccordionItem(title='Picture1')
        src = "picture1.png"
        image = MouseWidget(source=src)
        # add image to AccordionItem
        item.add_widget(image)
        root.add_widget(item)


        item= AccordionItem(title='Picture2')
        src = "picture2.png"
        image = MouseWidget(source=src)
        # add image to AccordionItem
        item.add_widget(image)
        root.add_widget(item)

        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

> Every time I add anything it seems like it shuts the whole program down.

This sounds like your changes crashed the program. You should check the output of your program by running it in a terminal. It will print information about the error that can help you track down your mistakes.

Comment: Inclement, you are a legend. Thank-you so much. I will certainly run kivy in the terminal from now on. Just seeing this code has taught me more than spending the last two days trying to figure this stuff out.